# Get text selection after time elapsed from webpage

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to get the text selected and also the DOM element along with where the ending of the text selection offset was in the webpage some seconds after the selection completed.

So like you highlight some text and if in 3 seconds that text is still highlighted, then I want to run some code that has as parameters the highlighted text and the DOM element that was nearest ancestor of the text.

I found there is this `selectstart` event,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/selectstart_event

and also the `selectionchange` event but I don't see a `selectend` event.

Some ideas were along these lines:

```
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', () => {
  // if (Math.abs(Date.now().getTime() - process_request_start.getTime()) / 1000 <= 5
  // if (is_processing_request === true) {
  //   return;
  // }

  setTimeout(() => {
    if (is_processing_request === true) {
      return;
    } else {
      is_processing_request = true;
      console.log(document.getSelection());
      is_processing_request = false;
    }
  }, 5000);
});
```

So I am looking for elegant code examples that provide/emulate a selectend, I had some working ideas using setTimeout but looking for any other solutions, prefer working code and not assuming any Jquery/libs, just native DOM environment.

Comment: Think the other way... Instead of implementing a `selectend`, you can instead set a flag at `selectstart` and listen for a `mouseup` event on the document, in the mouseup callBack, check if your flag is there. If yes it means you just arrived from a select event... then use the `window.getSelection` method to check the `startContainer`, get range at `anchorNode` and `focusNode` (that's the selected content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular problem, `clearTimeout` is your friend! You just cancel the timeouts until the time has elapsed (I shortened it to 2 seconds for this example):

```js
let waiting = null;

document.addEventListener('selectionchange', () => {
  if (waiting) clearTimeout(waiting);
  waiting = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(document.getSelection().toString());
    waiting = null;
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus viverra diam quis aliquet pulvinar. Donec fringilla feugiat elit, vitae pretium turpis suscipit et. Integer tempus massa pellentesque arcu sagittis iaculis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis faucibus vestibulum tempus. Morbi at dolor rutrum, malesuada ex sed, tempor nisl. Aenean viverra accumsan accumsan. Suspendisse dignissim augue tellus, quis sollicitudin enim dignissim nec. Nunc mollis vehicula nibh, sed suscipit diam tristique vitae. Nam efficitur massa quis ultrices lacinia. Nunc consequat interdum nunc, vel luctus risus faucibus vel. In arcu diam, bibendum ac enim vel, dignissim vehicula quam. Donec non justo scelerisque, hendrerit est rhoncus, consectetur mi. Pellentesque a lorem eget ex placerat sodales eget sit amet metus. Phasellus aliquam vitae neque vel suscipit.

In in nisl tristique, dictum justo ut, consectetur risus. Suspendisse congue dignissim orci, scelerisque accumsan massa ornare vel. Sed finibus ultrices felis, eu ultrices magna consectetur nec. Proin eu fringilla risus. Cras id posuere ex, sed porta dui. Integer id dolor massa. Cras dui ante, congue a odio non, pulvinar faucibus nisi. Nunc in ex non quam rutrum tempus sit amet ac neque. Vestibulum blandit vulputate massa, ut tincidunt magna dictum id. Vivamus laoreet auctor sollicitudin. Duis eu quam ac lacus faucibus imperdiet sodales eu nisl. Integer auctor commodo turpis, a ultricies sem lacinia iaculis.

Quisque id mattis neque, ut dignissim lectus. Curabitur ex libero, rutrum sed massa a, ultricies fringilla justo. Pellentesque in interdum felis, et aliquet ante. Praesent mauris leo, pretium quis lectus non, ultricies elementum neque. Nam suscipit ullamcorper neque sed iaculis. Maecenas placerat nisl et convallis hendrerit. Suspendisse molestie erat non leo cursus, in maximus sem facilisis. Ut non magna quis purus pellentesque auctor sed sed lorem. Aenean sed iaculis metus, at bibendum libero. Pellentesque in est nec ipsum maximus rutrum in vel dui. Duis porta laoreet dolor, aliquet eleifend mi dapibus consequat.

Mauris posuere tempus libero ut ullamcorper. Aenean ac accumsan enim. Quisque ex felis, pretium euismod dui et, euismod malesuada sapien. Etiam et tempus nulla. Quisque aliquet aliquet risus dapibus vestibulum. Etiam blandit leo odio, ac fringilla ante molestie nec. Sed commodo ex a finibus commodo.

Fusce sed fringilla tellus. Fusce id sagittis ipsum. Vivamus lacus neque, interdum et enim et, ultricies consectetur quam. Aenean lacus augue, placerat id odio vitae, imperdiet sodales mauris. In ornare est sit amet vestibulum interdum. Fusce ultrices, mi non mollis condimentum, est ligula dictum arcu, sed hendrerit magna dolor et ex. Morbi faucibus interdum mattis. Duis vel luctus sem, vitae porta elit. In gravida, leo at laoreet iaculis, mi odio ultrices nulla, sed dictum metus enim ac mauris. Sed odio est, consequat vel turpis et, accumsan accumsan libero. Maecenas nec luctus quam. Aenean et lobortis libero, quis pulvinar felis. Vestibulum sed dolor ornare, ultrices justo non, aliquam felis. Mauris sagittis rutrum mi, sit amet imperdiet lorem luctus non. Praesent ac tortor maximus, facilisis diam sit amet, rutrum nunc. Fusce sit amet lectus pretium, vehicula arcu laoreet, elementum justo.</div>
```

Comment: awesome, worked as desired. Now looking for a way to get a x-y positioning & the respective DOM element, I want to put a tooltip popup at above this selection